# Installation error "no package specified" - trying to install slidify from github in windows

Tags: r, github

**When I tried git-hub install, using:**

```
install_github('slidify', 'ramnathv')
```

**But I got the follwing message:**

```
> install_github('slidify', 'ramnathv')
Installing github repo slidify/master from ramnathv
Downloading master.zip from https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/archive/master.zip
Installing package from C:\Users\6E86~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYD4xRM/master.zip
Installing slidify
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/bin/i386/R" --vanilla CMD INSTALL "C:\Users\  \
 ע\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYD4xRM\devtools1f901f6d4e5e\slidify-master"  \
  --library="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.0/library" --install-tests 

Warning: invalid package 'C:\Users\ע\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYD4xRM\devtools1f901f6d4e5e\slidify-master'
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Error: Command failed (1)
```

**I also tried downlowding "slidify-master.zip" and installing it localy using:**

```
 install.packages("c:/r/packages/slidify-master.zip", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

**but nothing seems to happen, and the package is not installed:**

```
> library(slidify)
Error in library(slidify) : there is no package called ‘slidify’
```

**my sessionInfo() is:**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Hebrew_Israel.1255  LC_CTYPE=Hebrew_Israel.1255   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Hebrew_Israel.1255 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Hebrew_Israel.1255    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_1.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.4   evaluate_0.5.5 httr_0.3       memoise_0.2.1  parallel_3.1.0
[6] RCurl_1.95-4.1 stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.1.0    whisker_0.3-2
```

**any ideas?**

Comment: Did you try specifying the arguments?  i.e. `install_github(repos = ..., username = ...)`

Comment: I think it's because R sees the package name as `slidify-master`, which is invalid.  I'm sure @Ramnath will be along shortly to help you out.

Comment: I think it has something to do with Windows and encoding. Are you able to install any package at all from github. Can you try `install_github("knitr", "yihui")` so that we can isolate the problem being `slidify` or your being able to install packages from github.

Comment: The problem presisted when I tried to install other packages from Github. Seems it has to do ith the user name, and the directory where the downloads are stored.

Answer (score 1):

The problem presisted when I tried to install other packages from Github.
Seems it has to do ith the user name, and the directory where the downloads are stored.
I created a **new user in windows** with a simple name (no spaces, no special characters) and the installation succeeded !